# SQL Server - don't select if not unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I found a lot of questions about selecting unique, but not ignoring non-unique completely.

**I don't just want the first of each value, I want to actively avoid all records with a value that appears more than once.**

```
MyTable
id | col1 | col2
1  | a    | Some thing
2  | b    | Stuff
3  | b    | Other stuff
4  | c    | Some other thing

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [col1 is unique]
```

Should return row 1 and 4 only, since in `col1` value `b` appears more than once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inner select gets only `col1` that are unique. To get the complete row you need to use the outer select as well

```
select * from your_table
where col1 in 
(
  select col1 
  from your_table
  group by col1
  having count(*) = 1
)
```

Comment: @Matt . . . Your comment doesn't make sense.  Juergen's answer looks correct to me (with the possible exception of a singleton `NULL` value, but assuming not-`NULL` is reasonable).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Agreed

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I never said it doesn't work in fact I explicitly commented that it does, I am taking issue with the part of the answer that says "you need to use outer select as well" because you don't in fact need to given that the OP is looking for the unique record.  If looking for the duplicate/non unique then this technique would be more needed.  When looking for the unique using an aggregation on the rest of the columns such as MAX or MIN would suffice, which I answered to show that possibility.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
with tmp as (
select f1.*, count(*) over(partition by col1 order by col1) nb
from MyTable f1
)
select * from Mytable f2 inner join tmp f3
on f2.id=f3.id and f3.nb=1
```

or

```
select * from (
      select f1.*, count(*) over(partition by col1) nb
      from MyTable f1
              ) f2 
where f2.nb=1
```

or

```
with tmp as (
select col1 from MyTable 
group by col1 
having count(*)=1
)
select * from MyTable f1
where exists
(
 select * from tmp f2
 where f1.col1=f2.col1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Esperento57's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40917804/1043380) which uses `COUNT(*) OVER`. But because you are wanting the records where Col1 is unique you can actually do it in a single `group by` with aggregation as well.

```
DECLARE @MyTable AS TABLE (id INT, col1 CHAR(1), col2 VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (1,'a','Some thing'),(2,'b','Stuff'),

(3,'b','Other stuff'),(4,'c','Some other thing')

SELECT
    MIN(Id) as Id
    ,Col1
    ,MIN(col2) as col2
FROM
    @MyTable
GROUP BY
    Col1
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: Beware: not all data types can be used here. Which types work and don't depends on the version of SQL Server in use.

Comment: Why you should say that you **Voted up** in an answer?

Comment: @Sami I was showing an alternative to Juergen to prove a point.  My preference and what I would normally suggest is the COUNT(*) OVER that Esperrento answered and I was making that clear.  You have commented a couple of generic comments now not in regards to whether answers are right, wrong, or need to be tweaked is there something bothering you in particular?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to use window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) as cnt
      FROM MyTable t
     ) t
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

If you have a primary key on the table, then the fastest method (with an appropriate index) is probably:

```
select t.*
from MyTable t
where not exists (select 1 from mytable t2 where t2.col = t.col and t2.pkid <> t.pkid);
```

For this, you want an index on `MyTable(col, pkid)`.